# CDKpipeline - Cannot set lambda layer in a stack called from multiple stages in a pipeline

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-cdk-typescript

I want to set multiple stages with the same stack in a cdk pipeline. But I am getting the following error when bootstrapping my cdk project

```
C:\dev\aws-cdk\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\aws-lambda\lib\code.ts:185
      throw new Error(`Asset is already associated with another stack '${cdk.Stack.of(this.asset).stackName}'. ` +
            ^
Error: Asset is already associated with another stack 'msm-customer'. Create a new Code instance for every stack.
    at AssetCode.bind (C:\dev\aws-cdk\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\aws-lambda\lib\code.ts:185:13)
    at new LayerVersion (C:\dev\aws-cdk\node_modules\aws-cdk-lib\aws-lambda\lib\layers.ts:124:29)
    at new CustomerStack (C:\dev\aws-cdk\lib\CustomerStack.ts:22:17)
```

After debugging the code I found out that it is the layer declaration in the "CustomerStack" that is causing the issue. If I comment the layer section or if I keep only one stage in my pipeline then the bootstrap cmd works successfully. .

Pipelinestack.ts

```
 // Creates a CodeCommit repository called 'CodeRepo'
        const repo = new codecommit.Repository(this, 'CodeRepo', {
            repositoryName: "CodeRepo"
        });

        const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, 'Pipeline-dev', {
            pipelineName: 'Pipeline-dev',
            synth: new CodeBuildStep('SynthStep-dev', {
                //role: role,
                input: CodePipelineSource.codeCommit(repo, 'master'),
                installCommands: [
                    'npm install -g aws-cdk'
                ],
                commands: [
                    'npm ci',
                    'npm run build',
                    'npx cdk synth'
                ],
                
            })
        });

        pipeline.addStage(new PipelineStage(this, 'dev'));
        pipeline.addStage(new PipelineStage(this, 'uat'));
        pipeline.addStage(new PipelineStage(this, 'prod'));
```

PipelineStage.ts

```
export class PipelineStage extends Stage {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StageProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        new CustomerStack(this, 'msm-customer-' + id, {
            stackName: 'msm-customer'
            env: {
                account: process.env.ACCOUNT,
                region: process.env.REGION,
            },
        });
    }
}
```

CustomerStack.ts

```
import { Duration, Stack, StackProps } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import * as apigateway from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigateway';
import * as lambda from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda';
import * as iam from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam';
import * as ec2 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2';
import 'dotenv/config';

export class CustomerStack extends Stack {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        //define existing role
        const role = iam.Role.fromRoleArn(this, 'Role',
            `arn:aws:iam::${Stack.of(this).account}:role/` + process.env.IAM_ROLE,
            { mutable: false },
        );

        //define layer
        const layer = new lambda.LayerVersion(this, 'msm-layer', {
            code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('resources/layer/customer'),
            description: 'Frontend common resources',
            compatibleRuntimes: [lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X],
            removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY
        });

        const lambdaDefault = new lambda.Function(this, 'default', {
            runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
            code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('resources/lambda/customer/default'),
            handler: 'index.handler',
            role: role,
            timeout: Duration.seconds(20),
            memorySize: 256,
            layers: [layer],
            allowPublicSubnet: true,
            vpcSubnets: { subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC }
        });

        //rest of the code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to create three stacks with the same name (`msm-customer`). This will not work, since you are deploying all three to the same environment (account/region).

Your options:

1. Do not specify `stackName` and let CloudFormation generation it for you. The values will be unique.
2. Specify unique values (e.g. `'msm-customer-' + id`)
3. Deploy to different environments.